# bash copy file to link's reference

Tags: bash

Given this configuration :

```
../dir1/file1
../dir2/link-to-file1
../dir2/fileX
```

And I want to copy fileX to ../dir1/file1, but if I go:

```
dir2$ cp fileX file1
```

then

`dir2/file1` is no longer a link to file1 so that file1 and fileX are different files.

Is there a `cp` option to do that, or do I need to use some other operation.

***UPDATE***

In dir2

```
dir2$ ln -s ../dir1 (this creates link to dir1)
dir2$ cp fileX dir1
```

But is there a way of copying to the file through the link to the file?

Comment: Ack. I see. I will make the link to the directory instead of the file. Then I can copy to ````linkedir/file1````

Comment: Sorry, I find your question confusing. Are you talking about symbolic links to a file or directory? Is `link-to-file1` a symbolic link or a file? Could you show `ls -l`-like directory listings or something created by `tree` instead. Can you show the situation that you have, the situation you want, and what you are currently getting? Are hard links ever involved in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And I want to copy fileX to ../dir1/file1, but if I go:
>
> dir2$ cp fileX file1

<strike>Then use the correct target directory as intended:
dir2$ cp fileX ../dir1/file1</strike>

**Edit:**

```
dir2$ cp -L fileX file1
```

or

```
dir2$ cp fileX $(readlink file1)
```

This will produce this behaviour:

```
before:
dir1/file1
dir2/file1 -> ../dir1/file1
dir2/fileX

after:
dir1/file1 (with content of fileX)
dir2/file1 -> ../dir1/file1
dir2/fileX
```

Comment: It is the result I'm looking for, but not the operation. ````dir1```` is actually a very long path, not such a neat command as the one you give.

Comment: Ah, now I get it. I edited my answer.